# Win32::OLE with C# DLL and returned objects

Tags: c#, perl, ole, activeperl

I've created a working example calling a `C#` DLL from ActivePerl using `Win32::OLE`. However, as expected `out` parameters on the `C#` side are not updated on the `perl` side, but also 'complex' types (such as `List<int>` instead of `int[]`) do not work.

While I can probably stick to the basics of `int`, `string`, and arrays of such, is there a way to return these complex types to `perl` apart from serialising as a `string`? At the moment, an attempt to return `List<int>` as below simply results in an undefined variable.

**perl**

```
use Win32::OLE;
Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => 3); # to check I'm not missing any exceptions

my $dll = Win32::OLE->new('TestDLL.TestClass');
my $result = $dll->GetIntList(); # $result is undef
```

**C#**

```
public List<int> GetIntList()
{
    return  new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

I've also added debugging statements to the above in C# to confirm it is called and the list has 3 members before returning.